# Finding absolute screen position of an AlertDialog

Tags: android

I want to find the position (x,y) in pixels of the top left corer of an `AlertDialog`.

I used the following but it isn't working, it always returns zero:

```
myAlertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().x
```

I have searched and found how to set the position of the dialog but never how to get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int dialogLocation[] = new int[2];
myDialog.getLocationOnScreen(dialogLocation);
```

Then dialogLocation[0] will contain the x-value, dialogLocation[1] will contain the y-value.

Comment: You could add a view to the dialog and use that.